# how can I make this query not CaSeSeNsITIVe?

Tags: sql, ruby, string, where-clause, sql-like

how can I make this query not Case sensitive?

```
  @courses = Course.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using: oracle, sql-server, mysql... Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a Postgres database then you might want to consider [`ILIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) which is the case insensitive version of `LIKE`:

```
@courses = Course.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

Answer (score 4):

A typical solution is to turn both values to lower case before comparing them:

```
@courses = Course.where('LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?)', "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

Depending on your RDMBS, `LOWER()` might not be available.

Also depending on your RDBMS, there could be more efficient options available (since using a string function basically defeats an existing index). For example in MySQL, you set a case-insensitive collation on the concerned column, which will make all string comparisons case-insensitive by default, while allowing the use of an index.